# CSS Animation not working. (keyframes between font families) Alternative?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, tween

I apologize in advanced, I know there must be some simple solution but I'm just not finding any.

Right now I'm using this simple technique to swap fonts on a webpage as an animation. The problem is that only the latest version of Chrome seems to know what I'm trying to do. Is there an alternative to this in jQuery perhaps?

```
   @keyframes switch {
0%   {font-family: Comic Sans;}
50%  {font-family: Arial;}
100% {font-family: Comic Sans;} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick rendition of your keyframe animation in jQuery.

```js
var $switcher = $('#switcher');

function switcher() {
  $switcher.toggleClass('arial comicsans');
}

setInterval(switcher, 1000);
```

```css
.arial { font-family: Arial; }
.comicsans { font-family: Comic Sans'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="switcher" class="arial">This is a test</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Makes sense too. Thanks.